# PHP Laravel Nova how to return saved values of multiselect

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-nova

I have a Multiselect in one of my resources in my `Laravel` Nova application and when I choose some values and save them they get stored in the Database. If I want to edit the resource, the Multiselect is empty -> the stored values do not get displayed. How can I achieve that they get returned?

here is my code

```
return [
     Multiselect::make('Cars', 'carslist')->options($this->getCars()),
]


public function getCars()
{
    $opts = Car::get()->pluck('name', 'name');
    return $opts;
}
```

Comment: are you using https://github.com/arku31/NovaMultiSelect package ?

Comment: @AhmedAboud Yes I am - kind of. I don't really understand the example on the github page though, so I am probably not using it correctly... :-s

Comment: do a dd($opts); to check if its a numeric array